# Can there be a guide to what interruptions and skips can be made during parts of davening?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, hefsek-interruption

Can there be a guide to what interruptions and skips can be made during parts of davening? I'd like to see such a guide and think it would be extremely helpful to the users of Mi Yodeya.

Comment: Don't some siddurim have this akready

Comment: In the back of Tefillat Hashem that I have, there is a table of what to do when a part of davening is interrupted.

Comment: http://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Someone_who_comes_late_to_Davening

Comment: Do you mean teHillas Hashem?

Answer (score 1):

There is an English sefer Priority in Prayer which is a quality and easy to use sefer for these issues. If I remember correctly its Hebrew title is Avnei Yoshfei.

Answer (score 0):

There is a book *Shegiyot mi-Yavin* which is dedicated to helping with various mistakes in prayers and brachos.

Comment: welcome to mi yodeya. consider adding some info. on the book...